# ¿Cómo puedo evaluar un campo de fecha y obtener el resultado y también conservar los valores nulos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente resultado que me arroja la consulta de la tabla VENTAS, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me aparezcan los registros con la fecha "2021-01-27" y también los registros NULL en la condición de WHERE?

[image: Tabla Ventas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

necesitas la sentencia *IS NULL* para las fechas nulas en combinación con un *OR*.

Por ejemplo para la seleccionar fechas nulas o iguales '2022-03-27'

```
SELECT * FROM VENTAS WHERE FECHA IS NULL OR FECHA = '2022-03-27 00:00:00.000'
```

Por cierto, si no te interesan las horas te recomiendo utilizar una columna de tipo *Date* en FECHA en lugar de un *Datetime*